# Mysql Database: Joins sums and group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, left-join

I have two tables OrderUpdate and DailyProduction

**ORDER_UPDATE**

```
itemid  packages    ordercode
1       10          ORANGE
2       20          ORANGE
3       40          ORANGE
1       25          APPLE
2       50          APPLE
3       100         APPLE
```

**DAILY_PRODUCTION**

```
date    itemid  packages    ordercode
28-Sep  1       5           ORANGE
20-Sep  1       2           ORANGE
1-Sep   3       4           ORANGE
1-Sep   1       5           APPLE
15-Sep  2       5           APPLE
30-Sep  3       1           APPLE
```

And I want following as a result

```
itemid  packages    ordercode   ready   remaining
1       10          ORANGE      7       3
2       20          ORANGE      0       20
3       40          ORANGE      4       36
1       25          APPLE       5       20
2       50          APPLE       5       45
3       100         APPLE       1       99
```

Comment: What did you try to get desired result?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you can `left join` table `order_update` with an aggregate query that sums the packages for each `(itemid, ordercode)` in table `daily_production`:

```
select ou.*, coalesce(dp.ready, 0), ou.packages - coalesce(dp.ready, 0) reamining 
from order_update ou
left join (
    select itemid, ordercode, sum(packages) ready 
    from daily_production 
    group by itemid, ordercode
) dp on dp.itemid = ou.itemid and dp.ordercode = ou.ordercode
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir, this is exactly what i wanted :)